# Develop a starter wizard in react js web app

Tags: reactjs, redux

My question is a bit generic, I would like to create an optional initial tour, in which all the functions of my web app are illustrated step by step.
For example, those found at the entrance to management or even games.
My specific question is how to create the tour in such a way as to force the user to select that specific key and do that specific step without being able to use the other functions.
Everything must be achievable in react js

Comment: I would search the web for inspiration, there are probably packages for this. You can alos just look for inspiration in the code e.g here:
https://github.com/uptick/react-interactive-tutorials

Comment: exactly what I was talking about thanks I will try to take inspiration from this thanks a lot